# Storing and Receiving filtered options

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, charts

So I have multiple asp charts on-screen, each have a set of drop down filters to filter the charts either by a date or another parameter (customers,suppliers). The charts and dropdown filters are all dynamic and the data is driven from a database.

What would be the best way to save these filters when leaving the page or closing the application and those chosen filters are still active.. ?

Comment: cookies, maybe ? Or keep these preferences in db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies or Session variable. Cookies will keep on leaving the page and closing the app but you can have really big ones and have to depend on the user to keep and accept it. Session would also be good but it wouldn't keep after closing.

Comment: Yes I was thinking cookies. How would I use cookies to store multiple selected items from check boxes and then assign these back to the drop-down list..

Comment: Could store the selected items in an array and read that if the cookie exists, this is where it could lead to a really big cookie. I had tried storing the data in a custom object in the cookie in the past but I couldn't get it to read, maybe you will have better luck.